# Local CircleCI reports "Unexpected environment preparation error: error looking up self container id: Found multiple cgroups for outer container"

Tags: linux, docker, continuous-integration, circleci-2.0

I am getting the following error when I run `circleci build` locally on Ubuntu 18.04. The build runs perfectly inside the hosted CircleCI.

```
====>> Spin up Environment
Build-agent version 0.0.5359-1e92f70 (2018-05-05T01:50:55+0000)
Error: Unexpected environment preparation error: error looking up self container id: Found multiple cgroups for outer container

Step failed
Task failed
Error: error looking up self container id: Found multiple cgroups for outer container
```

CircleCI version:

```
circleci version: 0.0.5358-1e92f70
Build Agent version: 0.0.5359-1e92f70
built: 2018-05-05T01:50:55+0000
```

Docker-ce version:

```
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

I installed Docker exactly as specified on the [website](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#upgrade-docker-after-using-the-convenience-script), including setting the [usergroup](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/).

I used the instructions [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/local-cli/) to install CircleCI, which is this command: `sudo curl -o /usr/local/bin/circleci https://circle-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/releases/build_agent_wrapper/circleci && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/circleci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: CircleCI Developer Advocate*

There is currently a bug with the Local CLI. Should be fixed within 48 hours.Once it's fixed, running `circleci update` should download the fix.

This type of question would be answered more quickly on [CircleCI Discuss](https://discuss.circleci.com).

Comment: Hey @JasoonS this should be fixed. Once running circleci update pulls the update it should work for you now. Thank you for reporting this.